# I'm making a Console Application Game (C#), and I'm running into Stack Overflow Error. How to avoid?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

My game has multiple methods for each state of the game and these methods call each other where applicable. This is causing a Stack Overflow Error after a while. Is there any way to avoid this, perhaps a workaround?

Edit: As the user below suggested my code is basically:

```
void a()
{
    b();
}

void b()
{
    a();
}
```

In this code I intended to use recursion in order to change game states.
Is there any way to reset the stack so it doesn't cause an overflow error and then return to the methods.

Possible Fix: (Did this just delay the Stack Overflow or has it gotten rid of it?)

```
int tracker;
void start()
{
    a();
    resetter();
}

void a()
{
    b();
}

void b()
{
    if (tracker > 10)
    {
        tracker = 0;
        return;
    }
    else
        tracker++;
    a();
}

void resetter()
{
    start();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: It's impossible to say what's causing your overflow without seeing the mentioned methods.

Comment: Hello Cody, welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [mcve] first, and then update your question with relevant info and code so that others can help you.

Comment: It is called cross recursion. Try to build a terminal branch in one of this functions to deal with stackoverflow.

Comment: But they aren't supposed to directly terminate because I need to use both functions are game states. I'm looking for a way to reset the stack and then continue on with the code again.

Comment: Then you will have to introduce a condition which will return out of (one of) the methods.

Comment: @CodyCodiferusPetitt I see your update just now: this made the actual fix. After `b` is called 10 times, the recursion comes to an end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're doing something like:

```
void A()
{
  B();
}
void B()
{
  A();
}
```

This, by definition, will always cause a stack overflow. This is basicly because of how the stack works. Say you call `A` first, the moment this method calls `B`, the parameters/variables/... for this method are put on the stack. 
Then, this method (`B`), calls ´A´; the moment that happens, it will put its parameters on the stack.

The data on the stack is cleared after a method returns. But these two methods will never ever return... They keep on calling one another, something like:

```
A()
  --> B()
    --> A()
      --> B()
        --> A()
          --> B()
            --> A()
              --> B()
               --> A()
```

As you can see, more and more stuff is put on the stack, causing your overflow.

You will want your recursion to stop to fix this. You can do this by introducing  a stopping condition in either method which will `return`.

If you wish a more concrete answer to your question, please add some code. But since you're talking about A calling B, which is calling A, the above pseudocode should be adequate.